# Structural controllability of networks

Tags: matrices, matlab, control-theory, linear-control

I want to check the structural controllability of a given network from a given input node.

In Matlab, controllability can be verified using Kalman rank condition (`ctrb`). However, function `ctrb` computes powers of (adjacency) matrix $A$ up to $n-1$, where $n$ is the size of $A$. This is inefficient for larger networks because of computational issues (e.g., finite word length).

My network is directed and is of order greater than $25$ nodes and I want to check the controllability (or, at least, structural controllability) of the network from each node. Input matrix $B$ is a vector of size $25$ where only one element is non-zero, i.e., I want to check the controllability from one node at a time independently.

Is there any way to check the controllability or at least structural controllability of a network if the input matrix is given?

Comment: How do you define the controllability of a network? Are you sure that Kalman's controllability test applies here?

Comment: I am not sure about its numerical stability, but you could use the [Hautus lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma). I haven't looked into it myself, but maybe one can do some clever tricks with similarity transformations, like a Schur decomposition.

Comment: I tried using eigenvector test, but still numerical issues making be difficult. I have seen some graph related techniques to find minimum number of inputs need to bring the network to be structurally controllable using maximum matching theorem. But I don't know if A and B are given, how to check structural controllability of a network.